# Is there a header file for sha256?

Tags: c++, linux, header, cryptography, sha256

I'm using linux and I just need an existing header for sha-256; I have tried a lot of code blocks, none of them worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sha256.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input = "abc";
    string output1 = sha256(input);

    cout << "sha256('"<< input << "'):" << output1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Padded Hash Input:

`0x61626380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018`

How can I add the `sha256.h`?

Comment: @Niall This is not my native language so i made some wrong thank you to fix it.

Comment: Here is a lightweight header only library:
https://github.com/okdshin/PicoSHA2/blob/master/picosha2.h

Answer (score 3):

Not in the STL. You could utilize a library of your choice (e.g. OpenSSL):

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void foo()
{
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, str.c_str(), str.size());
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
}
```

I guess your example is from [here](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function). If this is the case, you could simply copy/paste the files from the site and build them with your project.

Comment: i'm just beginner so i'm asking again sorry about that.

openssl/sha.h :no such a file it said. what am i suppose to do?

Comment: On linux you have to install the developer package of openssl. Here on Ubuntu it is `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. This will install into `/usr/include` and then could be found by the compiler. Don't forget to link against the ssl library.

Comment: That is a question of the build environment you use... and is therefore off topic.

Comment: Adding openssl codebase to your project is pretty heavy. Here is a header only version:
https://github.com/okdshin/PicoSHA2/blob/master/picosha2.h